# Subsequence convergence in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

I recall a fact that for functions $f_1,f_2,\ldots\in L^1$ such that $\|f_n-f\|_1\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, there exists a subsequence $f_{n_i}$ that converges to $f$ almost everywhere.

Is this still true if we replace $L^1$ by $L^p$, and $\|f_n-f\|_1$ by $\|f_n-f\|_p$?

Comment: Yes, it's true. The proof is pretty much the same.

Comment: That's essentially, more generally, how the completeness of $L^p$ is proved, aka [Riesz-Fischer Theorem](http://www.math.purdue.edu/~zhang24/RieszFischer.pdf).

Comment: One can easily show that convergence in the $L_p$ norm implies convergence in measure. Then use the fact that a sequence that converges in measure has a subsequence that converges a.e.. (This last result is also due to Riesz, I believe.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is similar to what julien linked to, but I think it is worth sharing:

**CLAIM** Suppose that $f_n\in {\mathscr L}^p(X)$ is such that $\displaystyle \sum_{n\geqslant 1}\lVert f_n\rVert<+\infty$. Then $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geqslant 1}f_n $ converges a.e. in $X$, is in ${\mathscr L}^p(X)$ and $$\left\lVert\displaystyle\sum_{n\geqslant 1}f_n\right\rVert \leqslant \sum_{n\geqslant 1}\lVert f_n\rVert$$

**P** Let $M=\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\lVert f_n\rVert <+\infty$. Note $\left\lVert\displaystyle \sum_{k\leqslant n}|f_k|\right\rVert\leqslant \displaystyle \sum_{k\leqslant n}\lVert f_k \rVert $. 
Define $h_n=\displaystyle\left(\sum\limits_{k\leqslant n}|f_k|\right)^p$. Then $h_n\in {\mathscr L}^1(X)$, $h_n$ increases and $\lVert h_n\rVert_1\leqslant M^p$. By Levi's theorem, there is $h_0\in \mathscr L^1$ such that $h_n\to h_0$ a.e. $X$. It follows $h=\displaystyle\sum_{k\geqslant 1}f_k$ converges (absolutely) a.e. $X$. Let $g_n=\left|\displaystyle\sum_{k\leqslant n}f_k\right|^p$. Then each $g_n\in \mathscr L^1(X)$ and $g_n\to |h|^p$ a.e. on  $X$, and $g_n\leqslant h_n\leqslant h_0$ a.e. on $X$. By Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, $|h|^p\in\mathscr L(X)$, and $$\int_X |h|^p=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X \left|\displaystyle\sum_{k\leqslant n}f_k\right|^p=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lVert \displaystyle\sum_{k\leqslant n}f_k\right\rVert^p\leqslant\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k\leqslant n}\lVert f_k \rVert\right)^p= \left(\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\lVert f_n\rVert\right)^p$$

**COR1** If $f_n\in {\mathscr L}^p(X)$ is such that $\displaystyle \sum_{n\geqslant 1}\lVert f_n\rVert<+\infty$, then $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geqslant 1}f_n $ converges in the ${\mathscr L}^p$ norm to some $f\in\mathscr L^p(X)$.

**COR2** The space $\mathscr L^p(X)$ is complete, for

**PROP** A normed space is complete iff $\displaystyle \sum_{k\geqslant 1}x_k$ converges whenever $\displaystyle \sum_{k\geqslant 1}\lVert x_k\rVert$ converges.

Comment: Looks good, +1. Maybe you should add a few words to explain why it gives what the OP wants.

Comment: @Julien Because one can always find a *rapidly Cauchy* subsequence of a Cauchy sequence and then the claim applies.