# Consider the sequence $f_n(x) = (\sin(πnx))^n , n = 1, 2, ...,$ on the interval $[0,1].$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Consider the sequence $f_n(x) = (\sin(πnx))^n , n = 1, 2, ...,$ on the interval $[0,1].$ Prove that for any $δ > 0$ there is a set $E ⊂ [0,1]$ with $m(E) > 1−δ,$ and a subsequence $f_{n_k} (x), k = 1, 2, 3...,$ such that $\lim_{k→∞} f_{n_k} (x) = 0$ for $x ∈ E.$

Not sure what to do.  Want to construct a set $E$ as above with $f_n$ going to zero in $L_1$ norm.  Then it would follow.

Comment: Since $$\|f_n\|_1=\Theta\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},\right)$$ it is worth to first choose $n_k=(k+1)^\nu$ with $\nu>2$ then prove that $\lim_{k\to \infty}f_{n_k}(x)=0$ holds outside a set with small measure.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: How did you calculate that $L^1$ norm? If this calculation is correct, you are done, because each $L^1$ convergent sequence has a sub sequence converging a.e. Hence, you could even choose $E$ to have measure $1$.

Comment: $|f_n(x)|$ is a $\frac{1}{n}$-periodic function and $$\int_{0}^{1/n}\sin(\pi n x)^n\, dx=\frac{\Gamma((n+1)/2)}{n\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(1+n/2)}=\Theta(n^{-3/2}).$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I hope you don't mind my (more elementary) proof below. Is it easy to see that the integral is given by the quotient of $\Gamma$ functions? I essentially only know the definition of the $\Gamma$ function :)

Comment: No problem to me. The identity follows from the fact that $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(x)^{m}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}x^{m}(1-x^2)^{-1/2}\,dx $$ and from the Euler Beta function identity: $$\int_{0}^{1}x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}\,dx = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}.$$ From the Euler product for the $\Gamma$ function it follows that $$\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(n+m)}=\Theta(n^{-m}).$$

Answer (score 1):

Let us estimate
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left\Vert f_{n}\right\Vert _{1} & = & \int_{0}^{1}\left|\sin\left(\pi nx\right)\right|^{n}\, dx\\
 & \overset{y=\frac{n}{2}x}{=} & \frac{2}{n}\cdot\int_{0}^{n/2}\left|\sin\left(2\pi y\right)\right|^{n}\, dy\\
 & \leq & \frac{2}{n}\cdot\int_{0}^{n}\left|\sin\left(2\pi y\right)\right|^{n}\, dy\\
 & = & 2\int_{0}^{1}\left|\sin\left(2\pi y\right)\right|^{n}\, dy,
\end{eqnarray*}
where I used that $y\mapsto\left|\sin\left(2\pi y\right)\right|$
is $1$-periodic in the last step.

Now observe that $\left|\sin\left(2\pi y\right)\right|^{n}\leq1$
and $\left|\sin\left(2\pi y\right)\right|^{n}\xrightarrow[n\rightarrow\infty]{}0$
as long as $\left|\sin\left(2\pi y\right)\right|\neq1$. But $\left|\sin\left(2\pi y\right)\right|=1$
holds only for $y\in\left\{ \frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}\right\} $, i.e.
on a finite set, hence on a null-set. Thus, $\left|\sin\left(2\pi y\right)\right|^{n}\xrightarrow[n\rightarrow\infty]{}0$
almost everywhere.

Using dominated convergence, we conclude $\left\Vert f_{n}\right\Vert _{1}\xrightarrow[n\rightarrow\infty]{}0$.

It is well-known (cf. [Subsequence convergence in $L^p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611355/subsequence-convergence-in-lp)) that every $L^{1}$-convergent sequence $\left(f_{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$
has a subsequence $\left(f_{n_{k}}\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ so that
$f_{n_{k}}\left(x\right)\xrightarrow[n\rightarrow\infty]{}f\left(x\right)$
almost everywhere, where $f$ is the $L^{1}$-limit.

Hence, we can even take $E\subset\left[0,1\right]$ with $m\left(E\right)=1$,
because there is a subsequence $\left(f_{n_{k}}\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$
converging to zero almost everywhere.