# Is $\{f\in L^2(X): f\circ T=f\}$ closed in $L^2(X)$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

> Let $(X,\mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a probability space. Assume $T:X\rightarrow X$ is measure preserving, i.e. $\mu(T^{-1}(A))=\mu(A)$ for all $A\in \mathcal{A}$. I want to check if $U:=\{f\in L^2(X): f\circ T=f\}$ is closed in $L^2(X):=\left\{f:X\rightarrow \Bbb{R}: \int_X |f|^2 ~d\mu<\infty\right\}$.

I think this is true and I would prove it as follows. Let $(f_n)_n$ be a convergent sequence in $U$, say $f_n\rightarrow f$. I want to check if $f\in U$. Let $x\in X$ arbitrary, then $$f(T(x))=\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n \right)\left(T(x) \right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(f_n(T(x)) \right)\stackrel{f_n\in U}{=}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$$ so we have shown that $f\in U$ and hence by definition $U$ is a closed subset of $L^2(X)$.

Does this work or am I wrong?

Comment: The limits to be considered (for $f_n$ and $f_n\circ T$) are not pointwise limits but limits for the $L^2$-norm.

Comment: If you check a subset is closed in $L^2$, then you have to assume $f_n\to f$ with respect to the $L^2$ norm, i.e $\int_X |f_n-f|^2 d\mu\to 0$.

Comment: @AnneBauval aha okey I see, let me try I will edit the answer.

Comment: Hint: prove that $T\mapsto f\circ T$ is a linear isometry on $L^2(X).$ Imo this method is more elegant than taking sequences (though less "intuitive", but I find this word overused and ill-defined, often simply meaning "to which we are more used, but we are too lazy to change our habits").

Comment: @AnneBauval what is a linear isometry?

Comment: You know what a linear map is, and an isometry is a map preserving the distance (i.e. here: the norm, i.e. here: check that $\int(f\circ T)^2=\int f^2$).

Comment: But could I also say that $\phi:f\mapsto f\circ T-f$ is continuous and hence $U=\phi^{-1}(\{0\})$? @AnneBauval

Comment: $\ddot\smile$ Precisely! My hint was a step towards this.

Comment: ah, but then I don't see why I need your hint

Comment: It is easier to first prove the contiuity of $f\mapsto f\circ T$ (since it will be a linear isometry hence its operator norm will be $1$), and then derive that of your $\phi.$

Comment: Ah so I need continuity of $f\mapsto f\circ T$ or $T\mapsto f\circ T$ because in your first comment you wrote $T\mapsto f\circ T$ which confused me a bit @AnneBauval

Comment: Woops yes sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145167/discussion-between-user123234-and-anne-bauval).

Comment: @AnneBauval Do you have any thoughts on my answer? I think the OP's proof can be made to work if one sees that $L^2$ (infact $L^p$) convergence implies pointwise convergence a.e. along a subsequence.

Comment: @esoteric-elliptic, we are on the way (in the chat) to build a "more elegant" proof, not using sequences, and experimenting general ideas which may be fruitfully reused in other circumstances.

Comment: @AnneBauval Sounds good, I'll look forward to your proof :)

Comment: @esoteric-elliptic of course this is a way to fix it, but how convoluted!

Comment: Doesn't seem convoluted to me. It's one of the most frequently used results in Measure Theory, in my experience. @AnneBauval

Comment: The fact that if $T$ is measure-preserving then $f\mapsto f\circ T$ is a automorphism of the normed vector space $L^p$ (i.e. linear and normed-preserving) is direct and does not need such a detour by sequences. @esoteric-elliptic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My above answer is wrong since the convergence is not pointwise. So in discussion with Anne Bauval we have figured out the following proof.

**Proof** Let us define $$\phi:L^2(X)\rightarrow L^2(X); f\mapsto f\circ T-f$$ we want to check that $\phi$ is continuous. To do so let me define $$\psi:L^2(X)\rightarrow L^2(X); f\mapsto f\circ T$$ and first check that $\psi$ is continuous. Here one can use the following fact:

**Fact:** Every isometry $g:(X,d_X)\rightarrow (Y,d_Y)$ is continuous.
Indeed if we fix $\epsilon >0$ and take $\delta =\epsilon$ then for all $x,x'\in X$ s.t. $\|x-x'\|_X<\delta$ we have $$\|g(x)-g(x')\|_Y=\|x-x'\|_X<\epsilon$$And hence $g$ is continuous.

Now using this fact it is enough to show that $\psi$ is an isometry. For this  remark that $\psi$ is linear, therefore $$\begin{align}\|\psi(f)-\psi(g)\|_2&\stackrel{\text{linearity}}{=}\|\psi(f-g)\|_2=\|(f-g)\circ T\|_2\stackrel{*}{=}\|f-g\|_2 ~~~~~~~~(1)\end{align}$$where in $*$ I used the fact that $T$ is measure preserving. Indeed since $T$ is measure preserving I know that $\|h\circ T\|_1=\|h\|_1$. Taking $h=\rho^2$ we get that $\|(\rho\circ T)^2\|_1=\|\rho\|_2^2$. But this is equivalent to say that $\|\rho\circ T\|_1=\|\rho\|_2$, taking $\rho=f-g$ justifies $*$.

So we conclude that $\psi$ is an isometry and using the fact deduce that $\psi$ is continuous (i.e. for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta>0$ s.t. $\|f-g\|_2<\delta\Rightarrow \|f\circ T-g\circ T\|_2<\epsilon$)

Now using that the difference of two continuous maps is again continuous gives me that $U=\phi^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed in $L^2(X)$.

Comment: @AnneBauval, hope this works now

Comment: Yes, just 1 remark: in the chat I convinced you that $\|\psi(\rho)\|_2=\|\rho\|_2$ by using the trick $h=\rho^2$ but I also told you that a direct proof of $\|h\circ T\|_p=\|h\|_p$ for any $p\ge1$ and any $h\in L^p$ (if $T$ is measure preserving) is as easy as the proof for the particular case $p=1.$

Comment: Perfect thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can make your proof work with some modifications. Assume $\{f_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ is a sequence in $U \subset L^2(X)$, converging to $f\in L^2(X)$ in the $L^2$ norm. Then, there exists a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}_{k\ge 1}$ such that $$f(x) = \lim_{k\to\infty} f_{n_k}(x)$$
$\mu$-almost everywhere ([see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861261/show-that-there-is-a-subsequence-of-f-n-n-that-converges-to-f-almost-every?noredirect=1&lq=1), it's a fairly common result). Therefore, for almost all $x$, we have
$$f(T(x))=(\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} f_{n_k})(T(x))=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left(f_{n_k}(T(x))\right)\stackrel{f_{n_k}\in U}{=}\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}f_{n_k}(x)=f(x)$$
i.e., $f\circ T$ and $f$ agree except possibly on a set of measure zero. Since elements of $L^2(X)$ are equivalence classes of functions (two functions are in the same equivalence class if they agree almost everywhere), we have $f\circ T = f$.

---