# convergence in $L^p$ implies existence of function that bounds subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Question: Let $\{f_n\}$ converge to $f$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, $1 \leq p < \infty$. Show that there exists a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ and $g \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ so that $f_{n_k} \to f$ a.e and $|f_{n_k} | \leq g$ a.e.

My attempt: I am able to show that the existence of subsequence that converges a.e to $f$ however I am not sure how to obtain the function $g$. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/611355/121671)

Comment: @Mittens the question u linked involving the series $\sum f_n$, however I don't think the function $g = \sum f_{n_k}$ has finite norm.

Comment: The idea is to first choose a subsequent $f_{n_k}$ such that $\|f_{n_k}-f_{n_{k-1}}\|_p<2^{-k}$. Then apply the summation result in the link (notice that $\sum_k\|g_k\|_p<\infty$ with $g_k=f_{n_k}-f_{n_{k-1}}$. That such subsequence $f_{n_k}$ exists follows from the fact that $f_n$, being convergent in $L_p$, is a Cauchy sequence in $L_p$.

Comment: @Mittens The subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ I had constructed was from the result that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure so there exists subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ that converges a.e to $f$. However, if I would set the function to get $\sum_k g_k$ where $g_k = f_{n_k} -f_{n_{k-1}}$ then why should $|f_{n_k}| \leq g$ a.e?

Comment: $G=\sum_k|g_k|$ converges a.s and in $L_p$. Thus $f_{n_k}=\sum^k_{j=1}g_{j} + f_{n_1}$ converges almost surely and in $L_p$ to $f'=f_{n_1}+\sum^\infty_{k=1}(f_{n_{k-1}}-f_{n_k})=\lim_kf_{n_k}$. It follows that $f'=f$ almost surely. Also, $|f_{n_k}|\leq G$.

Comment: @Mittens I see it now! thank you!